# Add photo above in the form & mysql

Tags: php, html, image, forms

I try writing code to upload and second image and result is save in the database but when upload the pictures in folder images takes only one with name eg. **1.jpg2**

Code Normal:

Upload.php

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save_data.php" method="POST"> 
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> 
 E-mail: <input type="text" name = "email"><br> 
 Phone: <input type="text" name = "phone"><br> 
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br> 
 Photo2: <input type="file" name="photo2"><br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Add"> 
 </form>
```

Save_data.php

```
<?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $email=$_POST['email']; 
 $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 $pic2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']);

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("test_db") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$pic', '$pic2')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

View.php

```
<?php
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("test_db") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
$select_all="SELECT * FROM employees";
$select_all_query=mysql_query($select_all) or mysql_error();
$select_all_count=mysql_num_rows($select_all_query) or mysql_error();
$i=0;
while ($select_all_count > $i ) {
    $out_name=mysql_result($select_all_query,$i,"name");
    $out_email=mysql_result($select_all_query,$i,"email");
    $out_phone=mysql_result($select_all_query,$i,"phone");
    $out_photo=mysql_result($select_all_query,$i,"photo");
    $out_photo2=mysql_result($select_all_query,$i,"photo2");
    $i++;
    echo ("$out_name<br />");
    echo ("$out_email<br />");
    echo ("$out_phone<br />");
    echo ("<img src='http://127.0.0.1/upload/test/images/$out_photo' width='10%'><br />");
    echo ("<img src='http://127.0.0.1/upload/test/images/$out_photo2' width='10%'><br /><br />");
    }
?>
```

Certainly the change will want to **Save_data.php** :/

Comment: You are at risk of `mysql injections`. Learn more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Don't insert `$_POST` data directly! It's a major security issue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Also, don't use `mysql_connect` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php


See : http://xkcd.com/327/ and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: you say for how data is stored know, but I'm looking something to record multi images into a form.. :/

Comment: You don't have any code to move the `2nd` image to a `tmp` folder and then copy it. But you really need to fix the security issues with your code.

Comment: I try to do and I get,how to done;...

Answer (score 0):

In moving the images from tmp to target, you have code only for 'photo', you need to implement the same code for 'photo2' also.

Comment: maybe you is easy to show me how to come out why i does everything...thanks

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pJq19W0o0u0J:www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/278836/image-and-form-field-upload-problem+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a and http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/269945-why-functionmove-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/ - This is why you shouldn't use old crappy vulnerable code.

Comment: Look at this bit `//Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))` You have nothing in your code to move the `2nd` image.

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target.'/'.$photo) & ($tmp_name, $target.'/'.$photo2)) I've put so wrong but we have to put it;..